# Is it possible to use reference type alias with pointer operator to declare a reference to pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, type-alias

I have a simple example here: I used type alias using `using` keyword for a reference type then I want to know whether I can use that type alias with pointer operator(*) to declare a reference to pointer:

```
int main(){

    using ref_int = int&;

    int x = 10;
    int* p = &x;

    //int*(&rpx) = p;
    //ref_int * rptrx = p; // pointer to reference is not allowed.
    *ref_int(rptrx) = p; // rptrx is undefined

}
```

- Because as a matter of curiosity when I used the Element-type of `std::vector<int>::reference` I wanted to combine it with pointer operator `*` to declare a reference to pointer:

  ```
  int* ptr = new int(1000);
  std::vector<int>::*(reference rptr) = ptr; // error: expected expression
  ```
- But I can to use pointer type alias combined with reference operator "&" to declare it:

  ```
  using pInt = int*;

  int i = 57;
  int* ptrI = &i;
  pInt(&rpInt) = ptrI;

  cout << *rpInt << endl;
  ```

** I know I cannot have a pointer to a reference because a reference is just an alias name for an already existing object while a pointer is an object thus we can have a pointer or a reference to it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't have a pointer to a reference in C++.  In C++, references are just aliases for the thing that they refer to, the standard doesn't even require them to take up any storage.  Trying to use a reference alias to make a reference to a pointer will not work because using the alias will only ever give you a pointer to a reference type.

So, if you want a pointer to the thing the reference refers to you just use

```
auto * ptr = &reference_to_thing;
```

---

If you want a reference to a pointer that syntax is

```
int foo = 42;
int* ptr = &foo;
int*& ptr_ref = ptr;
```

Comment: "I wanted to combine reference type alias with pointer operator to declare a reference to pointer not the contrary". This is my issue. anyway thank you.

Comment: @Maestro I've updated the answer to explain why you can't use a reference alias to build a reference to a pointer.